# Here API - Autosuggest requiring parameter not required (in the documentation)

Tags: here-api

I am trying to use the Autosuggest feature from Here API following this documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html

The documentation says only the "q" parameter is required but I am doing the following query and getting the following error:

URL query: `https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?q=new+y&limit=5&lang=en-US&apiKey=xxx`

Response:

```json
{"status":400,"title":"Required parameter missing. One of mutual exclusive parameters 'at', 'in=circle', 'in=bbox' should be present","correlationId":"43ab125b-4f59-4255-8699-210e3acd053a","requestId":"REQ-aff498e0-ec75-45a9-998e-12b4ffa60d04"}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have missed this part of the doc:
`One of "at", "in=circle" or "in=bbox" is required.`
I guess it is not shown explicitly as required (*) because it depends on two different fields.

In the previous API version (v6) this field is not required, I don't know why this is required now.
If someone needs a globally auto-suggesting it won't cover. Even if I can use a long radius covering the world but it looks not right as the field is required.

Comment: I believe the idea is that this API relates to our search APIs and the intent is to find points of interest near a location, not across the planet.